# My flutter app logs out after hot restart,Cannot make app stay logged in even after restart

Tags: flutter, dart

i implemented login  after onboard screen and logged in but unfortunately each time i restart my app i am brought back to the welcome page.i also want to implement a splash screen   but don't know how to add it in the *MyApp* material root  widget since i have returned the introduction/on boarding page and set the welcome page to come after it.I  also want to find a way to check auth state after one time introduction/on boarding screen. I'll appreciate

```
    int initScreen;

   Future<void> main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
       await Firebase.initializeApp();

       //on Board Screen Intialization
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       initScreen = prefs.getInt('initScreen');
         await prefs.setInt("initScreen", 1);

           runApp(MyApp());
             }

     class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
       // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Introduction(),
      initialRoute: initScreen == 0 || initScreen == null ? 'onboard' : 'home',
  routes: {
    'home': (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
    'onboard': (context) => Introduction()
        },
       );
          }
         }


 class Login extends StatefulWidget {
 const Body({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
   _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
  }

        class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
   TextEditingController _email = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController _password = TextEditingController();
     isLoading = false;

          @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
            return Scaffold(
                  body: Background(
        child: isLoading == false
            ? SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "LOGIN",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/icons/login.svg",
                      height: size.height * 0.35,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
                    TextFieldContainer(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _email,
                        cursorColor: kPrimaryColor,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.email,
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                          hintText: "Email",
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextFieldContainer(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _password,
                        obscureText: true,
                        cursorColor: kPrimaryColor,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Password",
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.visibility,
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    RoundedButton(
                      text: "LOGIN",
                      press: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isLoading = true;
                        });
                        AuthClass()
                            .SignIn(
                                _email.text.trim(), _password.text.trim())
                            .then((value) {
                          if (value == 'Welcome') {
                            setState(() {
                              isLoading = false;
                            });
                            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Home()),
                                (route) => false);
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              isLoading = false;
                            });
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                SnackBar(content: Text(value)));
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
                    AlreadyHaveAnAccountCheck(
                      press: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) {
                              return SignUpScreen();
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                 ),
              )
              : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )));
           }
          }

                   
      class AuthClass {
        FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

      //Create account
     Future<String> createAcount(String email, String password) async {
       try {
  await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
          return "Account Successifuly Created";
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    return 'The password provided is too weak.';
         } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    return 'The account already exists for that email';
       }
     } catch (e) {
        return 'Error ocurred';
    }
    }

   //SignIn User
 Future<String> SignIn(String email, String password) async {
try {
  await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  return 'Welcome';
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    return 'No user found for that email.';
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    return 'Wrong password provided for that user.';
  }
  }}

  //ResetPAssword


  //SignOut
  void signOut() {
    _auth.signOut();
  }

  //try
  Future<String> Reset(
    String email,
  ) async {
    try {
      await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(
        email: email,
      );
      return 'Email sent';
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Error Occured';
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a "pre-login" screen, I usually call it Loading anyway, and on that screen I just bring a Circular Progress, just to give feedback to the user who is loading something.

Meanwhile, in initState, call a validate user method, where you check if you have any users logged in (of course, you should store this in SQLite, Shared Preferences or something like that). Depending on the return, you redirect to Login or to your Home.

Comment: Luis Otavio i Would appreciate if you provided the code for me so that i can easily understand what you are saying because im a beginner thanks.